# CreateTempFile returns No Such File or Directory in Pictures folder?

Tags: android, android-file

So here is my code:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File image = File.createTempFile(
      imageFileName,  /* prefix */
      ".jpg",         /* suffix */
      storageDir      /* directory */
);
```

However, my application intermittently throws error at `File.createTempFile`:

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory).
```

From the documentation of `File`:

```
Parameters:
prefix the prefix to the temp file name.
suffix the suffix to the temp file name.
directory the location to which the temp file is to be written, or null for the default location for temporary files, which is taken from the "java.io.tmpdir" system property. It may be necessary to set this property to an existing, writable directory for this method to work properly.

Returns:
the temporary file.

Throws:
IllegalArgumentException - if the length of prefix is less than 3.
IOException - if an error occurs when writing the file.
```

What are the possibilities of failing writing the temporary file? Since I point to external storage and my external sd card is plugged inside device.

Comment: Are you running on an API 23 (Marshmallow) devices? Did you request the storage permission at runtime?

Comment: No I am using 4.1.2 JB device. Btw this application is for in house only, so devices are defined and those devices running on Lollipop have no problem.

Answer (score 3):

The javadoc for [getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29) specifically states that:

> this directory may not yet exist, so you must make sure it exists
>   before using it such as with File.mkdirs().

After that, I think you should also still check to see if the directory exists.

Comment: But my device has Pictures folder, which is stored in internal SD Card and not in external SD card as I expected. Thus, the folder must be exist. CMIIW.

Comment: I suppose you can file a bug with AOSP?

Comment: I am not sure whether this is Android bug or my code is wrong (I am sure it is correct).

Answer (score 1):

```
File imageFile = null;
    try {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";

        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        boolean pictureDirectoryExists = storageDir.exists();
        if (!pictureDirectoryExists) {
            pictureDirectoryExists = storageDir.mkdirs();
        }
        if (pictureDirectoryExists) {
            imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
            mCurrentPhotoPath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();            }

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        LOGGER.error("E", exc);
    }
    return imageFile;
```

I know it is really old post but I had same problem. The reason of Exception is directory is not exists.